# Show Lebesgue integral $ \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 {x}}{x^a}\,dx$ exist for $1 < a < 3$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Show that the Lebesgue-Integral 
$$  \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 {x}}{x^a}\,dx$$
exist for $1 < a < 3$.

---

This is the exercise I have to do. I know of one criteria, which says: if $f$ and $g > 0$ and  $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$ and $g$ is Lebesgue-integrable $\implies f$ is integrable. Which is some corollary of the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Split the integral at $x = 1$, and analyse each part separately. Each gives constraints on $a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer did it. But what is my g(x) in eather case?